# Stirling's Formula and Logarithms

Tags: integration, inequality, logarithms

I'm going through the proof of Stirling's Formula and I'm not quite sure of the following line:

> Since the log function is increasing on $(0,\infty)$, we get
>
> $\int_{n-1}^n \log(x)dx < \log(n) < \int_n^{n+1} \log(x)dx$

The argument might be trivial, but I'm quite seeing it.  I tried solving both the left and right hand sides of the inequalities and for the left side I get 
$$\log\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}} - 1$$

I tried showing by induction that $\displaystyle\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}} \le n$ but it fails for $n=2$.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't if it can be useful: $\int_{n-1}^n \log(x)dx < \int_{n-1}^n\log(n)=\log(n)(n-n+1)=\log(n)<\int_{n+1}^n \log(x)dx$. Remember that log function is increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: You need to stick an e in the denominator there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the mean-value theorem for integrals $\int_a^b f(x) dx = f(c)(b-a)$ along with the fact that $\log$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above you can write the following inequality:

\begin{equation}
\log\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}-1<\log n\\\log\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}<\log n+1\\\log\frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}<\log ne\\ \frac{n^n}{(n-1)^{n-1}}<ne
\end{equation}

Now it is true the case $n=2$.
However I think it is better following the way suggested in the comment above:$\int_{n-1}^n\log x dx<\int_{n-1}^n\log n dx=\log n<\int_n^{n+1}\log xdx$

Answer (score 0):

To show
$\int_{n-1}^n \log(x)dx < \log(n) < \int_n^{n+1} \log(x)dx
$.

The basic result needed is this:

If 
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous
and $f(x) \ge g(x)$
on $[a, b]$,
then
$\int_a^b f(x) dx
\ge \int_a^b g(x) dx
$
with equality if and only if
$f(x) = g(x)$
everywhere on $[a, b]$.

A corollary of this
is that if
$f(x)$ is strictly increasing
on $[a, b]$
and $a < b$
then
$f(a)
< \dfrac1{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) dx
< f(b)
$.

All this says is that
the average value 
of an increasing function
is strictly between
its min and max values.

The reverse inequality
holds for
strictly decreasing functions.

Since
$\log(x)$ is increasing,
$\log(n)
\le \log(x)
\le \log(n+1)
$
for
$n \le x \le n+1$
with equality
only at one of the endpoints.

Therefore
$\log (n)
< \int_n^{n+1} \log(x) dx
< \log(n+1)
$.